# How to send Events between objects on the same level (Global Event Manager)?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Working on basic game, I came to the point where I need to communicate between 2 objects (let's say Tank and the Cannon). It is tile game, and when the Tank approach specific tile I need my Cannon to shot the Tank. When Tank gets that specific tile I want to dispatch some custom event and have listener in Cannon class body to make the shot happen. Other way I would have to check in ENTER_FRAME loop (inside Cannon body class) if the Tank touched tile that runs the Cannon shooting - but this is not elegant and efficient. The issue is complicated by the fact that the Cannon and Tank are added to the Engine (document class) and can't simply hear for each other, because they seat on the same level in display list.
Initially I could addEventListener to the Engine, but this way my document class would enlarge to the XXL size (all listeners functionality, all methods for game etc). What I would acomplish is to have event listener in every Cannon object (defined in body class) listening for Tank's dispatching the event. I saw some 'Centralized Event Manager' article in the net, but can't download full classes (broken link - http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/829/6/Centralized-Event-Management-in-ActionScript-3/Page6.html). 
So, basically summing this up: How 2 objects laying on the same level of displayList can communicate each other when something happens, and not involving document class, and ENTER_FRAME events...
Kindest Pawel

Answer (score 0):

You should have a dedicated Singleton (which I'll name `GameModel` from now on) that acts as a model in your game, namely, everyone listens to it to see what its happening. So, if your tank enters a danger area, you do `GameModel.instance.broadcast(/*your danger signal event*/)` in your tank class and `GameModel.instance.addEventListener(/*your danger signal event*/, /*your danger signal handler*/)` in your cannon class.

Comment: thanks for tips. This is what I was thinking about, but do not know how  to bite it... Would be great to see en example of that, but I am starting to make it on my own. Hope I can do it:)

Comment: it seems that is what I was looking for:) http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4/topics/81391